# Python- Writing a function using git log output

Tags: python, git, function, datetime, git-log

I have created a date variable for the commit date from a git log but I don't know how to convert this date into the week number in Python. I am just not understanding how to create a function in python that would create a new variable with values that draw on another variable. Below is my code- As you'll see I created a variable for the date of a commit and I want to use that date to find out the week number. I want to do this for every commit date and then print the results so I can view them.

```
import git
g = git.Git("dir_repo")
loginfo = g.log('--since=2015-03-01', '--date=short', '--pretty=%cn %cd')

datecom=g.log('--since=2015-03-01', '--date=short','--pretty=%cd')

import datetime

def week():
    return datetime.isocalendar(); 
weeknum=week(); 

print week(datecom)
```

I receive the following error:

```
$ python test23.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test23.py", line 13, in <module>
    weeknum=week();
  File "test23.py", line 12, in week
    return datetime.isocalendar();
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isocalendar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has issues on different parts:

1. `datecom` is your case is a unicode string of all date strings, so you have to split it into individual date strings first and then convert those to `datetime.date` objects.
2. `isocalendar()` operates on `datetime.date` objects and returns a 3-tuple of `(ISO year, ISO week number, ISO weekday)`, of which you apparently are only interested in the week number.

You could do something like this:

```
import git
import datetime

g = git.Git("path/to/git/repo")
loginfo = g.log('--since=2015-03-01', '--date=short', '--pretty=%cn %cd')
datecom = g.log('--since=2015-03-01', '--date=short','--pretty=%cd')

date_list = [datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
             for date_str in datecom.split('\n')]


def week(date_obj):
    _, week_nr, _ = date_obj.isocalendar()
    return week_nr

for date in date_list:
    print("{date} (week number: {week_nr})".format(date=date,
                                                   week_nr=week(date)))
```